# How can I open the properties of documents in a new page in my mobile application, which is just like an e-commerce application?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

[image: My App]

I want to open the properties of the document I clicked in a new page.

I have a collection called Status in Firebase and I have documents with properties in it.
How can I open the properties of documents in a new page in my mobile application, which is just like an e-commerce application?

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> getStatus() {
var ref = _firestore.collection("Status").snapshots();

return ref;} // this is my function for getting data
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are calling this function in Stream Builder:-

```
StreamBuilder(
    stream: getStatus(),
    builder:(context,AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
       if(!snapshot.hasData)
          return Center(child:CricularProgressIndicator());
       else if(snapshot.data!.docs.isEmpty)
          return Text("No Data");
       else{
         DocumentSnapshot doc=snapshot.data!.docs[0];
         print(doc['Your property/field name']);
         //above is just demo for printing content of first document as index is 0, You can use ListView for showing all docs
     }
  }
)
```